# Is there a way to specify tags per file and check them out?

Tags: git

I am fairly new to git and not quite sure how to ask this. My job still uses CVS and I am starting the push to move us away from it, however we have a custom build server that tags cvs checkins with a certain tag based on the latest checked in version of each java class as determined by our task tracker system. It then checks out each file based on the tag. It allows us to check out a version of the project based on what task we have marked for release. I'm curious if something like this is possible in git, and if so, how would this be accomplished. Thanks for the pointers. I've read the pro git book and still didn't really get an idea of whether this is possible.

Comment: If you are using repo tool for managing git projects then you can use versioned-manifest files as well. Yuo want this for single repo or multiple repos which are managed using manifest (.xml) files??

Comment: It would be multiple. In the hundreds actually.

Comment: So you are using repo tool to manage it??

Comment: We have our own custom built tool for it, but yes.

Comment: Then you can create the versioned manifest files. Just store SHA IDs in manifest files as revisions. Later you can use these versioned manifest files for release.

Comment: Also you can create a new repo for just storing these versioned manifest files in that way you just need to push tag in one repo i.e. the one you use to store versioned manifest files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags per file: no.  Check-out by tag: yes.

More specifically, a in git, tag is just another way to specify a particular commit.  Each commit has a "true name", one of those 40-character SHA-1 values like `676699a0e0cdfd97521f3524c763222f1c30a094`.  These true names are not useful for humans, so we give them meaningful names, either by labeling the tip of a branch (e.g., `master`) and then referring to a commit by its distance from the branch-tip (e.g., `master~3` would be "the third commit back from the tip"), or by a more-static name.

Branch tip names move—that's kind of the whole point of them, after all; having a branch named `master` and another named `develop` would not get us anywhere if we could never add commits to `develop` and then merge them back into `master`.  So we also need "non-moving names", and those are "tags".

To check out by tag, just do:

> `git checkout tagname`

Git will look up the corresponding commit SHA-1 and check out that particular commit, i.e., restore the entire work tree to the state it was in when the commit was made (not counting untracked and ignored files, of course).

Git will also give you a slightly scary message about a "detached HEAD" (which sounds like you've been guillotined), but it's really just telling you that you are no longer "on a branch", and if you make new commits, they will work just fine but *also* won't be "on a branch".  Because commits are logged, they are semi-permanent even if not "on a branch" (they stick around for a while until the log entry expires), but they can become hard to find, as branch-names (and of course tags too!) are the easy way to find commits.

---

Incidentally, as a CVS user, you might wonder how you can check out tag version "v1.3" of file `A` and use it with tag version "v2.7" of file `B`.  You *can* do this in git: start by checking out the desired tag for "all files" (let's say v2.7 for everything), and then extract the one file you want to revert:

```
git checkout v2.7
git checkout v1.3 -- fileA
```

You now have v2.7 of "everything" except for fileA.  If this combination is useful for some reason, though, the git philosophy is not "make a special way to check this out" but rather "now make a commit out of that, and give it a name":

```
# test test test, yes, this is what we need for Customer X
git status # make sure we're ready to commit
git commit -m "special version for customer X"
git tag customerX
```

You now have a tag you can use to name "v2.7 of everything, except v1.3 of fileA".  It's a commit, so it is permanent as long as it has a name (and we just gave it one, `customerX`).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation of replicating the CVS functionality could work. I'll give what you suggested a try!